# How to store a location and a station identifier using c# in a winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, mac-address

I am trying to design a system with multiple locations/stations to connect to the same database server.

However, I need to create an identifier for each location "Physical Address" and a station number "Physical PC" inside the location.

To make the idea a bit more clear please think about a Large POS system the belongs to a large corporation (corporation with multiple stores. Each store have multiple PC.)

This store number is an id that is generated when a new store is added to the database server by Administrator (ie, store_id = 100.)

Then each store will have multiple station ids. The station ID is an identifier generated when a new station is added to the database by an Admin as well (ie. station_id = 100254)

The thing that I am looking to solve for here is

1. How would I determine the the current station_id and location_id when the application Launches? The station_id and the location_id will have to be unique to a PC so when the application runs the system have the correct IDs.
2. How/Where would I be able to **securely** store the database connection string to establish a connection to a database?

The first thing that comes to my mind is

1. When setting up the new station "during the installation process" is to create a local file that has the string for the database connection.
2. Also create a second file that contains the unique value of the store # and the station #. In addition, store the MAC Address of the PC in the database, just in case this file get removed "the same ID can be retrieved"

I am not sure if my method is the way to go and if so, is having a local file to the PC a secure method?

My application is/will be designed using C# and winforms API.

Comment: does the users on the stations have a "login" mechanism? what are the "stations" role in general?

Comment: Can hostile user sniff your communication on the location's local network? is it wired/wireless? maybe you need also VPN here...

Comment: @yossico The user will have to login after the application runs. but I would need to know what location are the use logging in from and what location. I don't have the network setup but it does not matter as I would have to make sure the communication is secured. Probably via SSL

Comment: In that case I think a server side that wrap the DB operations with services is a good aproch like @AMember says, you can use WCF to do that

Answer (score 0):

1) I would not put connection string on the app itself. that is a security issue.

Can you not just call an api to do the DB stuff? that will be much more secured.

2) for the ID problem I would still go for the api approach and each app would request for a unique ID

on installation time, and embed it in the configuration file.

Comment: so the API will be located on the the server where the database is hosted? what would I need to pass for the server to know if this station already have an id or not? how can I ensure unique information?

Comment: @Mike I think he ment that the API is a collection on method that can be aproched via your WinForm - some kind of network service i.e. REST service. this way no one can touch your DB without passing your BLL in the serverside

Answer (score 0):

1. regarding the connection string

I would recommend in your case to use a WebService containing all the repositories needed by the clients, so no need to store any connection string on the client machine

2. regarding who you will detect the station Id and the location Id

I would recommend to link the mac address to the location ( unless for some reason, the machine was moved to different store which should be cleared from your system before they move it and to add again in the new store), also to add history for the users login that will hold the mac address and the computer name if you want and the windows user and what time he logged in and logged out, this way you will allow more flexibility in using your application, and not to restrict them to station id

hope this will help you

If you still have further questions, go ahead